# Translation difficulties and the meaning of 着くように

Tags: translation, usage

I'm trying to translate the following sentence from a book and I'm confused by its construction.

> 牛乳を飲み終わった人から、紙パックを自分の番号のケースに戻して席に着くように。

Which I assume would mean *"When people finish drinking their milk, they usually put back the card box in their own case."* A bit confusing already but this is the best I can manage, might already be wrong though.

However my biggest problem right now is making sense of 着くように in this sentence. I understand that ように means *in order to* or *as if* but I fail to see how it could connect to 着く and the rest of the sentence. Could it mean something like *"[the narrator] went as if putting back their box like people usually do when they're done drinking their milk"* or am I completely off track here?

Help would be appreciated thank you!

PS: If you're wondering, this is the very first sentence of a book called 告白 by 湊かなえ and I have no idea what it's *actually* about.

Comment: `度に着くように` >> should be「 **席**に着くように。」

Comment: Oh you're right I misread that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context,

> 「着{つ}くように」＝「着くようにしなさい」

In other words, this whole sentence is an ***imperative*** , which is why your translation "**When people finish drinking their milk, they usually ~~~~**" is highly inaccurate.  Sorry for being blunt, but I've gotta tell the truth so you could learn something.

The ように-imperative is quite common in giving instructions, but you would need to remember that you should not use it to speak to people of higher status.  In that case, 「～～ようにしてください」 or 「～～ようにお願{ねが}いします」 would be used instead.

> "As you finish drinking the milk, take turns in putting back the (empty) paper packs in your (assigned) case and then, go back to your seat."

Finally, when a phrase/sentence ends in 「**Verb in Dictionary Form + ように**」, it can mean another thing "**so that (verb phrase)**".

Whether it means that or it is used as an imperative depends entirely on the context.  If I said:

> 「神社で祈った。あの人と結婚できるように。」,

it would have to mean:

> "I prayed at the shrine so that I could marry that girl."

It should ***not*** mean:

> "I prayed at the shrine.  Be able to marry that girl!"

Comment: I didn't know about this usage of ように thank you for your detailed explanation. And don't worry about being blunt, being right is more important haha.

Answer (score 1):

着くように is a shortened form of 着くようにして下さい, which can be translated as "Make sure that you xxx xxx".

Answer (score 0):

席に着く means to take a seat so this would be "When you've finished drinking your milk, put it back in your numbered case and sit down"