# Grammar of verb + noun + から

Tags: grammar

I just read [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/44712/translation-difficulties-and-the-meaning-of-%E7%9D%80%E3%81%8F%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB) but was confused by a different aspect of the example sentence:

> 牛乳を**飲み終わった人から**、紙パックを自分の番号のケースに戻して席に着くように。

The question's answer is perfectly clear about the meaning, but I don't understand how the grammar of the part in bold works. When I see から I think of either 'from', 'because' or (if it's て-form) 'after'. None of these seem to work.

On it's own, the first clause (to me) reads

> from the person who has finished drinking milk

but such a translation clearly doesn't fit with the rest of the sentence.

Is it a geneal rule that

> verb-past + noun + から = as noun does verb

What about the tense/aspect of the verb? Some more examples would also be appreciated.

Comment: This is a good question, answered well by Shoko, but the title does not really fit. You are asking about this particular meaning of から after a noun phrase. The "verb" is only part of the qualifying verbal phrase 牛乳を飲み終わった, which has nothing specific to do with the question. Perhaps a better title would be "Meaning of から after a noun phrase", or something similar, though it's hard not to end up writing the answer in the question: "Sequential meaning of から".

Comment: @BrianChandler  You make a good point. I'm never sure whether ex post facto title changes are a good idea though. The current title relects the problem I thought I had, and therefore the problem other people might think they have. If you feel differently I have no problem with you editing the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to 明鏡国語辞典:

> から
>   〘格助詞〙
>   ❼ 順序を表す。「好きなもの**から**食べる」「子供**から**診察する」

And [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/45491/meaning/m0u/):

> 1⃣［格助］
>   ５ 動作・作用の開始順序や発端を示す。「先着の人**から**入場してください」

I think the から indicates the starting point of order, meaning 「～～から順番に」「～～から順に」, "starting from~~, in order from~~".

「牛乳を飲み終わった人から」≂「牛乳を飲み終わった人から*順に*」
"Starting from the person who has finished drinking milk, do ~~ in turn", hence the translation "As you finish drinking the milk, take turns in..."

I hope this makes sense.